# How to create an Apple Search Ads API certificate?

Tags: apple-search-ads

I wan to [setup Adjust](https://help.adjust.com/en/article/apple-search-ads-ad-spend#setup-in-apple-search) and it needs a certificate and private key from Apple's Search Ads page. When I am on the "Search Ads" > "API" page, there is NO 'Create Certificate' button or something else (of course I'm the admin).

Comment: Btw here is a screenshot [of the overview @ search ads](https://fromsmash.com/oSSfevvkOd-dt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate-based method is the old way to track ad spend in Adjust, now there's a new method that uses credential to get the data. You can refer to this guide here: https://help.adjust.com/en/article/apple-search-ads-ad-spend#add-apple-ads-account-in-adjust

Comment: No it still required the certificates